# Diff highlights in Visual Studio Code without Git

Tags: visual-studio-code, diff

One neat feature in Sublime Text 3 is [Incremental Diff](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/incremental_diff.html), which is very similar to the Git diff feature in VSCode, but it shows the diff since you first opened the file. It works for files that are not in a version-control system, and it's useful when quickly editing a file. I was wondering if something similar exists for VSCode. I love the diff provided by GitLens, but it's only limited to Git projects. I want to have it on every file I edit.